# Issue with base64 image in mPdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I have base64 image in database with some text. Like `[<img src='base64 image link'> What is your name]`. When I export data to pdf using mPdf, It was showing 404 for image and text will be show there in server website. In my local system it works fine. mPdf properly shows my images.

I have also checked PHP versions: local and live have the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at MPDF and it requires mbstring (less important) but also GD extension for PHP. Please check that your GD extension has the same version locally and on your live server.

You can check by running `php -a` and execute `var_dump(gd_info());`. It will return something like:

```
php > var_dump(gd_info());
php shell code:1:
array(12) {
  'GD Version' =>
  string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
```

Maybe some older versions of GD couldn't handle base64 encoded images?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Local and live has same version.